# Universal Metro apps and background tasks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How do I call code from my Shared Project to run in the background of the Windows Phone project?

To run code in the background on WP, I need to extract that to a new project and call that new project from my WP project. But to run the code I'd need to either:

- Extract the logic into the background project (but then I lose the advantage of a Shared Project)
- Duplicate the code

Is there a way to make a Universal Windows (Phone) App that executes some business logic in the background, **without** duplicating the code or losing the advantage of a Shared Project?

Edit:
This is the code that is called when I put it in a seperate project. It is not called when I put it in either the WP project, or the shared project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

namespace WindowsPhoneProject
{
    public sealed class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            taskInstance.GetDeferral().Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem.. Have you found a way to tackle this ?

Answer (score 1):

This Quickstart walks through how to create Background Tasks for Universal Apps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx

You should be able to create the class that derives from IBackgroundTask in your shared project.   If you only want to create the background task on the phone, then you can use a compile time directive like so:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
//  Code Here
#endIf
```

Comment: I've tried adding a new backgroundtask to my shared project and referencing it from the appmanifest. The following is all I get: `The program '[6084] Windows.Media.BackgroundPlayback.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).` I added some debug logging to the background task but nothing is printed.

Comment: Have you gone through the sample:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319/sourcecode?fileId=111812&pathId=1324331438
More resources as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090
Debug BackgroundTask:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj542416

Comment: I did, but all the code and documentation puts the background task in a  seperate project. And as far as I know I can't reference the shared project from my background task.

Comment: Just tried again. It works when I put a basic background task in a new project, but when I take the same task and put it in the Shared project, it's never called.

Comment: Background audio on phone is specific to phone.  Why are you putting it in the shared project?

Comment: The audio would be in a seperate project, that's not the problem. But I don't know where to put e.g. the scanning of the Music Library. If I put it in the foreground, the UI becomes unresponsive. That's why I'd like to put it in a background task, so the user doesn't have any hinder.